# Javascript acting differently in c# web browser

Tags: javascript, c#

In internet explorer, I am trying a code, it is working just fine, Upon running it in c# it will not change the width of the object i am making it manipulate. The code is very simple:

```
function fixstyles(){
if(document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-header-row')[1].children.length > 10){
alert('ye');
vv = document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-header-row').length -1;
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-header-row')[vv].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].style.width);
document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-header-row')[vv].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].style.display = 'none !important'; // checkbox
document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-header-row')[vv].getElementsByTagName('th')[7].style.width = '0px !important'; // checkbox
 }
```

it displays the alert saying '24px' and does not do any of the other functions, however when i run the same exact code natively in internet explorer, it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, JavaScript can't be run "in C#". I *presume* you are injecting the JS into the browser *from* C# but I see no code that indicates that which therefore suggests the answer is either incomplete or you don't fully understand the problem.

Comment: @James The injection method is not necessary because i already mentioned that i am seeing the alert, therefore the code was succesfully injected and the only thing in question is the code listed above.

Comment: Its probably a cache issue. Try clearing the cache when launching the website in IE and also clear the cache on your native browser. I've had these issues as well and found out it was just a browser cache issue.